# How to make a form blink on error input?

Tags: delphi

Maybe a beep and background flashes red? Any code snippet? Thanks

Comment: yikes, three of the most annoying ui dis-features (beeping, blinking and flashing) to signal an error?! Why not simply put a thick border around controls that have arroneous input? Thick because only changing the color would not help color-blind people.

Comment: I think you should open 1000 popup windows instead, to random web pages. That would be even MORE ANNOYING. :-)

Comment: Yay, I get to upvote a downvoted question, makes me happy.
Yes, I have a real use for this. I am writing a game for deaf people and the form flashes like a sonar echo locator. So while the reason the questioner want this for a bad reason, does NOT make it a bad question. Also, the Accepted answer did not answer the question. *sigh*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes a form Blink is a very bad GUI design, instead you can try one of these options :

- using a dialog message , like

_

```
Application.MessageBox('Your message of error', 'Errror', MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE + MB_ICONSTOP);
```

- using a image (icon) which represent a error status.
- using a [`TStatusBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TStatusBar) with a message indicating the error message.
- using a [`TLabel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TLabel)  in your form with a special font color (like `clred`).

finally the option which your choose depends of the type of your application and the kind of the error.

check this question for more advices [`Error Message Text - Best Practices`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117083)

Comment: while a dialog message is much better than beeping, blinking and flashing, I'd advise restraint in using message boxes. For real errors they are OK, but all these "are you sure" type of messages are only slightly less annoying than blinking, flashing or beeping...

Answer (score 1):

Even I don't agree with 'blinking' windows/messages here you have a small component example http://www.torry.net/vcl/labels/blink/blinklbl.zip  .

You can adapt the code to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to do the following:

Highlight (and focus) the control in error, either by sublty changing it's background colour or making the border bold or even making the field caption bold.  Or any combination.  As Marjan Venema said, be aware of people who are colour blind.

Lastly have an area of each form that can show validation errors - e.g. align a listbox or stringgrid or similar to bottom or top and toggle visibility depending on the number of errors > 0. You could even allow the user to click on the error in the grid/list to set focus on the offending field.

One of my apps actually stores these validation errors in a table, and allows the user to query the list to work through errors later on.

Pop up dialogs, and *blinking* should be used very sparingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a second, empty form at run time with the same size and position and show it as an overlay for a short time. You can use alphablending (AlphaBlend and AlphaBlendValue properties, see [this article](http://delphi.about.com/od/formsdialogs/a/fadeinmodalform.htm)) so that the form below will still be visible.

(This is a technique which I used as an additional visual hint while displaying a modal dialog - without blinking, of course)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [JvValidators](http://help.delphi-jedi.org/unit.php?Id=3026) from Jedi Lib. You can find more info on 
[Jedi's Project Portal](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/) and can download it on  [Sourceforge Jedi's page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/)

Take a look what I've done with it: [Gedean's Error Manager Framework demo](http://cid-b5acb83888fa39bf.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/ErrorManagerFramework.rar)

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

**A possible solution:**

Please refer to:

- [FLASHWINFO structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679348%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [FlashWindowEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679347%28VS.85%29.aspx)

They are defined in the `Windows.pas` unit as far as Delphis is concerned.

Set the proper handle to the HWND field of your FLASHWINFOHWND struct. Any VCL Control with a handle will do *et voilà*!

Tweaking the dwFlags and uCount fields allows you to have the behaviour you expect.

In your case, Blinking/Flashing the whole form is not a good idea to my opinion. Avoid to be too intrusive and/or annoying: Why not target the control where the wrong input occured or at least the status bar?

---

**Side note:**

Here is a snippet I sometime use to **alert user by means of flashing**:

```
procedure TForm1.Flash;
var
  FlashInfo: FLASHWINFO;
begin
  if (GetForegroundWindow<>Handle) then
  begin
    FillChar(FlashInfo, SizeOf(FLASHWINFO), 0);
    //
    FlashInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(FLASHWINFO);
    FlashInfo.dwFlags := FLASHW_ALL or FLASHW_TIMERNOFG;
    FlashInfo.hwnd := Handle;
    //
    FlashWindowEx(FlashInfo);
  end;
end;
```

Notice:

- It works if and only if the App's Main windows is not in the foreground (Flashing only if need be!).
- I call the method prior to a modal error notification and only in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way to do this, in Windows, is to use the [FlashWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API which allows you to flash the window border, and if it is not currently focussed, to flash the task bar icon.